# How to deploy Java desktop application using HSQLDB as central database on LAN?

Tags: java, client-server, desktop-application, hsqldb, lan

My project is a java desktop application that uses HSQLDB as its backend database on standalone machine and it works perfectly.Now i want to implement my application on Local Area Network(LAN) by making centralized HSQLDB database in such a way that multiple application instances should be able to read/write data in efficient manner. I expect suggestions and guidelines about how can i achieve this functionality ?

Comment: Run HSQL in server mode and make sure clients aren't blocked by firewalls: http://www.hsqldb.org/doc/guide/ch01.html

Comment: You may wish to consider using a different database engine, but HSQL can run in server mode as well

Comment: @MadProgrammer,@duffymo Thank you for your responses,i have just tried running HSQLDB in server mode but the problem comes when i try to open same database with two different instances of server. The .lck file is not allowing to reopen database.

Comment: @MadProgrammer Which one will be the best if i wish to consider other database engine ?

Comment: You shouldn't be connecting to the databse directly, but via the database server instance, you'll need to change the URL connection String. You could consider MySQL, PostgreSQL, Apache DB, Debry DB, there are plenty to select from and int will come down to what you want to achieve and get out of the database...

Comment: @MadProgrmmer Will you please show me some sample program ? or should i share what i have tried ?

Comment: Thank you all , finally i implemented this functionality i.e. Java desktop application using HSQLDB as central database on LAN.